# Не могу установить ссылку

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Скачал в Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin. Создал проект на Android. И сразу же проблема[image: Нужна ссылка которая подчеркивается красным]

Нету Xamarin.Support.V7.App. Посмотрел в ссылках проекта - нету. Посмотрел в нагете. Вот такая картина [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь чем то поможете

Comment: Не в тему, но...Чем вам не подходит официальный бесплатный Visual Studio Community 2019, который можно просто скачать без проблем с [сайта](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/) Microsoft?

Comment: Если вы имеете дело с Xamarin, то лучше всего иметь последнюю версию VS, т.к. регулярное обновление многочисленных библиотек и Android SDK гарантируется в этом случае.